# What does "of a kind" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I'm not referring to "one of a kind" or "first of a kind" but "**the two were of a kind**".  This turns out to be remarkably un-Googlable so I am having difficulty providing examples.  In context I have always assumed it meant that two things were in a unique category unto themselves.

Comment: maybe "they were two of a kind" => "the two were of a kind" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Two of a kind" means that there are two parts that make up the total. "The two were of a kind" is a little different because it doesn't imply that there are only two in that "kind", but that those two are in that "kind", where kind generally refers to a unique personality trait, state of mind, or way of looking at the world.

Answer (score 2):

It really means the same as it does in the context of the phrases "one of a kind" and "first of its kind." In this context, "kind" means (loosely) "a type or variety having specific quantifiable features." So for "the two" to be "of a kind" means that they have specific quantifiable features in common. The phrases "of a kind" and "of the same kind" are more or less semantically interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

It basically means that they share some common subset.

It can be used in a manner to exclaim that a group is special and out of the ordinary.

It is often used to express distaste at certian life choices in a manner that seems less overt or crass.  In this manner the exact definition is left indefinate so that the speaker can claim misunderstanding.